# Ethereum send transactions are unsuccessful when I run the node and miner in same machine

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I have started the Ethereum client using the Go Ethereum. And also started the Ethereum miner on the same machine.

Now node and miner are running in the single windows function.

If I try to send ether from one account to another account, it is not getting there successfully.

Everything is set up in private blockchain.

Steps I Followed :

1. I have installed the ethereum wallet.
2. Installed the ethereum go client, go ethereum.
3. Created the genesis file, created an account with some ethers in it.
4. Called the "geth init genesis file ......"
5. Check the account with some ethers in balance.
6. Started the miner in the same machine using the same network Id.
7. Created an another account using get client.
8. Now unlocked the account and sent some ethers to the newly created account.
9. Transaction came into miner logs, but it didn't get mined so the amount was not added to receiver.

What could be the problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you clarify what is your setup more precisely?

Comment: What do you mean by not getting successful, does is means you are getting any error, or your transaction is not mined?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh As you said mining is not happening so the ether is not reducing and increasing in corresponding accounts.